# HTML Video Tag in Internet explorer

Tags: html

Does HTML video tag works in IE browser. I have a little demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oamiamgod/X3fcA/3/). Its working in Firefox. I need to make it work in Internet Explorer as well.

```
<div class="content flowplayer is-splash is-closeable" id="vid1">
    <video id="mainVideo" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.webm" tabindex="0">    
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"></source>
    <source type="video/webm" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.webm"></source>
</video>    
</div>
```

Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, from IE9. IE6/7/8 do not support the `video` tag. Also, not all formats are supported by all browsers. On [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) there is a nice table of the formats supported by each browser.

Answer (score 2):

Webm should play in Iexplorer 9 and higher. It won't work in older Iexplorer versions, unless you use [Google Chrome Frame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) (or anything simular). Another option is to use Flash as a fallback option.

If that's not the issue, some servers need an .htaccess file to play video's online. The htaccess file should contain:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

If that's not the issue, check if the Webm is alright. You could use [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) It's free fast and good.

Answer (score 1):

You need [Google Chrome Frame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) to work in IE 6,7,8

For IE9 you need [WebM](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/webmmf) support

Check [this](http://www.youtube.com/html5) out

Answer (score 1):

you could potentially look at http://www.flowplayer.org as an alternative, native  support, but then falls back based on browser and version